# Terms clarification for Quotient space related questions.

Tags: general-topology

For the following two questions:

> a) Determine the quotient space of the torus surface $S^{1}\times S^{1}$ modulo the longitudinal circle $S^{1}\times \{1\}.$
>   b) Prove that $S^{2}$ is homeomorphic to the quotient space of the torus surface $S^{1}\times S^{1}$ modulo the 1-point union $S^{1}\vee S^{1}=(S^{1}\times \{1\})\cup (\{1\}\times S^{1})$ of the longitudinal circle $S^{1}\times \{1\}$ and the meridional circle $\{1\}\times S^{1}$.

I don't understand the use of the term modulo and also for part (b), I also don't understand the phrase "1-point union".   I am hoping someone can clarify what they mean mean, and what I need to do the question, in the sense, am I suppose to come up with a homeomorphic mapping or defined some sort of equivalence relation for (a) over the torus, and for (b) over the sphere.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: By 1 point union they mean those two sets already intersect at exactly 1 point and they want to consider union of those two sets

Comment: modulo and quotient have same meaning here

Comment: The question in a) is indeed very vaguely formulated. What is there to determine about that quotient space already defined and determined as a particular quotient space? As to what ''modulo a subspace'' means, it refers to the quotient of the torus through the unique equivalence relation which has the longitudinal circle as an equivalence class whereas all other classes are singletons (in other words, the equivalence that ''identifies'' all the points of the specified circle).

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik is (b) asking to show the longitudonal circles of the sphere are homeomorphic to the longitudonal circle as part of the torus on the (0,y,z) axis and similarly, the latitudonal circles of the sphere are homeomorphic to the meridional circle as part of the torus on the (x,y,0) axis.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ for (a), the circle on the (0,y,z) axis revolving around the z-axis generates the torus.  Is it asking me I need to show how a torus is homeomorphic to another torus with an equivalence relation defined over the circle on the (0,y,z) axis?

Comment: @SethMai: I am frankly not sure what the expectation behind the ''determine'' exercise is; visually speaking, this quotient of the torus looks like a ''strangulated doughnut'' if you permit the wording: imagine a rubber life ring that is constricted down to a single point somewhere along the ''equatorial circle'', with all the other longitudinal sections being actual circles (although of gradually decreasing radii, tending towards $0$ as they approach the ''point of constriction'' into which one of the original longitudinal circles has degenerated by taking the quotient).

Comment: @SethMai: furthermore, if we are to be rigorously speaking, in your presentation the torus is given as the direct square of the unit circle, and this direct product is not explicitly a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$; therefore, employing coordinates to reference the location of points would only make sense after fixing a certain homeomorphism between the direct-product torus $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1$ and the torus $\mathbb{T}$ defined as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Can I ask, how did you learn to get good at picturing quotient spaces in topology?  Also, at the more advanced level, are there more advanced tools that you learn that would help with verification what you visualize in your head is mathematically correct and not as a result of an episode down the LSD lane.

Comment: @SethMai you flatter me by saying I am good at picturing quotient spaces (that is not how I would describe myself); I don't think there are in general any ''advanced tools'', just a certain amount of spatial-geometrical visual intuition with which we are all endowed, to a greater or lesser extent. At any rate, whatever ''visual description'' one might come up with for a quotient space, one should try to rigorously formalize it and see if a homeomorphism could be established between this ''pictured'' structure and the given quotient space (this could be done in the particular case above).